# How to implement HashMap in PHP with Object Key

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, hashmap

What I want to implement is check how many times a coordinate exists(with `latitude` and `longitude`)

I need to iterate a JSON Array, and with bunch of `latitude` and `longitude`

what I think is similar by java, using a key-value pair, the key is object with two variables(`latitude` and `longitude`). and the value is the number of object exists.

So every time when I iterate a JSON array, I need to create a new object with `latitude` and `longitude`, and check whether this object exist in `Key`, if yes, value++, otherwise initial with value `1`

It's very simple to implement with Java by using `HashMap` and Override the `equal()` and `hashcode()` method in object to check whether the two object are equal.

How can this be implement by PHP? I know `array()` in php is equal to `hashmap` in java that have `key-value` pairs. But the key in `array()` cannot be `Object`

Comment: In this situation, I would use a 2D array (in PHP or in any other language): `array[latitude][longitude] = value`. You shouldn't find too many problems to adapt the input information to this reality.

Comment: @varocarbas It's a good idea, but is it efficient to get and set the whole 2D array? Because the coordinate data is very huge, every time I should check whether the coordinate exists in the array, if not, add it, otherwise, value++. Also after the whole iterate, I should iterate the array again to add the latitude, longitude and value into a CSV file.

Comment: From your statement I understood that the range of latitude/longitude coordinates lie within a narrow range; this is the kind of conditions where 2D arrays become handy. If the longitude/latitude values are too high (or there big gaps among them; for example: 1 and then 1000 and then 10000), 2D arrays would consume lots of memory. In that case, you might store both coordinates as a string (for example: $string_index = $longitude . "_" . $latitude) and rely on a dictionary-like array: `array[$string_index] = value`; it would slower but much more efficient from the memory point of view.

Comment: @varocarbas Thank you for the advise, The coordinate is within a huge range that maybe contains the whole world coordinate. What I think is to use two dimension array that with key-value pairs rather than regular `a[0]`, `a[1]`. So it will implement my function within `O(1)` time constant right? first I check for the `latitude` in the outer-array, `latitude` is the key, and all the others is the `value`, and then in the inner array, key is the `longitude` and value is the number of that `latitude` and `longitude` pair. Is this work efficient?

Comment: A bit difficult to tell. 1D is certainly much more efficient than 2D; but 2 arrays are also much less efficient than 1 array. On the other hand, the information in the 2 arrays might be populated/accessed in much quickly than in my dictionary proposal. It depends upon the size, how often will the arrays be accessed and how is the information expected to be used, etc. A priori (without knowing the exact conditions), I would firstly go for the 2D alternative if the size would be acceptable (what is apparently not the case); my second option would be the proposed dictionary-like approach...

Comment: ... very (memory) efficient, although a bit too slow to access the information. In case of having a too slow behaviour, I might do some tests with other approaches, like your 2-arrays alternative; but by bearing in mind that the memory migth be an issue. I might even consider a database alternative. In fact, I have done quite a few tests with PHP under kind-of-hard conditions and database-based approaches have proven to perform really well in comparison with memory-based ones for relatively small sizes.